# Error of unexpected ')' when using cut() function

Tags: r, categorization

so I'm trying to use the cut function to make a numeric variable into a categorical variable, and I keep getting an error of unexpected characters, but have triple checked my spelling so not sure what is wrong, can anyone help? this is the code:

[ca_timechcare_categorical:= cut(ca_timechcare,
break=c(0,36,72,108,Inf),

```
include.lowest=TRUE,

labels=c("Very_Low", "Low", "High", "Very_High"))]

dataset[,table(ca_timechcare_categorical)]
```

and this is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in "labels=c("Very_Low", "Low", "High", "Very_High"))"
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: have now corrected code as suggested below to:

```
dataset <- as.data.table(US_COVID19_study)

dataset[,ca_timechcare_categorical:= cut(survey_design_childcare,
                                                  breaks = c(36,72,108,Inf),
                                                  labels= c("Very_Low", "Low", "High", "Very_High"))]

dataset[,table(ca_timechcare_categorical)]
```

but now i get this error:

```
Error in `:=`(ca_timechcare_categorical, cut(survey_design_childcare,  : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

any ideas?? thanks again!

Comment: `break` is a reserved word. This problem can be simplified to `cut(1, break=0:2)`. Note that many function arguments are auto-expanded *without warning*, so one can do `cut(..., lab=c("Very_Low",...))`. It is both sloppy and pervasive in many packages; set `options(warnPartialMatchArgs=TRUE)` to see the warnings that are produced when partial-matching is done ... and then fix the code you can and submit bug-reports for code you cannot. (And then likely turn it off, because it can get tiresome.) Unfortunately, `break` is not partial-matched to `breaks` due to it being a reserved (special) word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using data.table and hence the vestigal operand `:=`
Two things: you are missing a comma in the brackets and its `breaks` not `break`

```
library(data.table)
irisdt <- as.data.table(iris)

irisdt[,new := cut(Sepal.Width,
                   breaks=c(0,36,72,108,Inf),
                   include.lowest=TRUE,
                   labels=c("Very_Low", "Low", "High", "Very_High"))]
```

Comment: hi, a new error just came up, I've edited my post to detail,, do you have any idea how to fix?

Comment: your data.table object ist US_COVID19_study.dt, not US_COVID19_study!